# String patterns that can be used to filter and group files

Tags: design, algorithms, language-agnostic, regular-expressions

One of our application filters files in certain directory, extract some data from it and export a document from the extracted data. The algorithm for extracting the data depends on the file, and so far we use regex to select the algorithm to be used, for example `.*\.txt` will be processed by algorithm A, `foo[0-5]\.xml` will be processed by algo B, etc.

However now we need some files to be processed together. For example, in one case we need two files, `foo.*\.xml` and `bar.*\.xml`. Part of the information to be extracted exist in the *foo* file, and the other part in the *bar* file. Moreover, we need to make sure the wild card is compatible. For example, if there are 6 files

```
foo1.xml
foo23.xml
bar1.xml
bar9.xml
bar23.xml
foo4.xml
```

I would expect foo1 and bar1 to be identified as a group, and foo23 and bar23 as another group. bar9 and foo4 has no pair, so they will not be treated.

Now, since the filter is configured by user, we need to have a pattern that can express the above requirement. I don't think you can express meaning like above in standard regex. `(foo|bar).*\.xml` will match all 6 file above and we can't identify which file is paired for a particular file.

Is there any standard pattern that can express it? Or any idea how to modify regex to support this, that can be implemented easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have in mind could be solved by *backreferences*. See, for example, here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx

or here

http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

An expression like

```
(foo([0-9])\.xml) .* (bar\1\.xml)
```

applied to the space separated list of file names will deliver you pairs like `foo1.xml`, `bar1.xml` as matches. Of course, you may have to solve the problem of bringing the files names into correct order before (or provide a reg exp which is indedependent from the order of files).

EDIT: concerning order of files: you could specify this with two different rules, since I guess you want your processing done in a specific order. So when the above expression delivers you a pair

```
(filename1,filename2)
```

you run the processing algo P with parameters

```
P(filename1,filename2)
```

and when the second rule

```
(bar([0-9])\.xml) .* (foo\1\.xml)
```

delivers you a pair

```
(filename1,filename2)
```

you call P with the order of the names switched:

```
P(filename2,filename1)
```

Of course, depending on your reg exp processor, you can also use newlines for separating the file names and use multiline matching. I used whitespace above just for easier demonstration purposes.

Comment: any idea how to provide reg exp independent of the order of the group?

Comment: @LouisRhys: see my edit

Comment: Sorry to keep asking, any idea how to make this work for group of n files? (e.g. if I want to group foo*.xml, bar*.xml, blah*.xml, ....)

Comment: @LouisRhys: my suggestion is not a good one for > 2 files. I guess easiest approach for that situation is to let the user enter n regular expressions, where each one is applied once to the whole list of files. I think you will need to implement backreference replacement for this case by yourself, to replace a backref in expression 2,3,4... with a match from expresion 1.

Comment: how does that work? What expression will the user enter as backref in expression 2,3,4 and how can we replace it?

Comment: @LouisRhys: you can define your own placeholder, using characters which are forbidden in filenames (or just use \1, \2 etc.) Then use a simple string replace, or a reg exp, or a small parser for replacing the placeholder; the appropriate thing depends on how complex the rules are and how and foolproof your solution must be.